# c++ 2017 Redistributable package - how to distribute

Tags: c#, c++, distribute, redistributable

I have problem with MS Visual Studio (VS) upgrading, the application need c++ redistribute package for program in c# with c++ libraries.

Actual we use VS 2012, where I need 2 files (msvcp110.dll and msvcr110.dll) from its VS Redistributable package, but if I try to copy files from VS 2017 c++ package, the application starting process end by exception on the other PCs.

Is it possible to move the application to other PCs (without VS) without installing c++ 2017 Redistributable package? It means only copy some files or some other actions without install process on the other PCs.

I would like to avoid to run install process on the others PCs, because standard users in our organisations can not run install process.

Examples:
c#:

```
[DllImport(dllPath + "main.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, ExactSpelling = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr Get_Default();
```

c++:

```
#define NAG_CALL extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) 
NAG_CALL const char *Get_Default(void)
{
  static char *value = NULL;

  if (value)
    free(value);

  return value = get_Default(); 
}
```

Thanks
Karel

Comment: You are need to run the appropriate MS redist package to install the needed runtimes see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235299.aspx

Comment: Deploy the correct DLLs.  If your program needs msvcr110.dll then the VS2017 runtime DLLs are as useful as a boomerang that doesn't come back.  Just copy them along with the rest of your executable files, stored in the same directory.